# Split a string and group by for aggregation

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, group-by

I have data of the form:

```
id  |  comma_string
abc123  | apples, pears, bananas
def456  | carrots, grapes, apples, pears
abc123  | oranges, apples
```

I would like:

```
id | fruit  | count
abc123  |  apples | 2
abc123  |  pears | 1
abc123  |  bananas | 1
abc123  |  oranges | 1
def456  |  carrots | 1
etc...
```

How can I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lateral join and `regexp_split_to_table()` to split the string, and then aggregate:

```
select t.id, s.fruit, count(*)
from mytable t
cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(t.comma_string, ', ') s(fruit)
group by t.id, s.fruit
order by t.id, s.fruit
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7960c3eea923ede6994dfd0be807b9b0)**:

```
id     | fruit   | count
:----- | :------ | ----:
abc123 | apples  |     2
abc123 | bananas |     1
abc123 | oranges |     1
abc123 | pears   |     1
def456 | apples  |     1
def456 | carrots |     1
def456 | grapes  |     1
def456 | pears   |     1
```

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot. I find this part hard to comprehend what's going on `cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(t.comma_string, ', ') s(fruit)
`, I'll do some reading

Comment: More specifically, what does this part at the end of that line do? `s(fruit)`

Comment: Welcome@DougFir. `s(fruit)` assigns a table alias and a column alias to the derived table that is generated by `regexp_split_to_table()`.

Comment: Ah I see. It's just new syntax for me, I've never created an alias for both a table and column at once. Thanks again, this works